# Python Poetry ImportError And Issues With Uninstalling

Tags: python, python-poetry

So I'm running into the "ImportError: cannot import name 'Application' from 'cleo'" with my poetry install, I read that some people with the same issue got it fixed by re-installing poetry.

However, this is the actual terminal output I'm receiving:

```
user@user-vm-ubu:~ curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall
Poetry is not currently installed.
user@user-vm-ubu:~ curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | POETRY_HOME=$HOME/.local python3 -
Retrieving Poetry metadata

The latest version (1.4.0) is already installed.
```

I just can't figure out why I'm not able to install, uninstall or use poetry at all.

I've tried to manually find and delete all the poetry files but nothing seems to be working. Does anybody have a good solution for this previously mentioned ImportError and/or uninstalling issue?

Comment: Resolved this issue by re-installing my VirtualBox Ubuntu installation completely. This was luckily an option for me as every file is stored in GitHub and my VirtualBox Ubuntu environment is just for coding purposes. I'm still going to leave this question here opened if someone does actually have some useful insight into this topic.